# QGIS polygon linking

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm using the most up to date version of QGIS. I have created a vector layer of multiple polygons that form areas of one larger area. I cannot get the polygons to connect at the corners or the edges.

Comment: How are the settngs of your snapping tool?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Since the "most up to date" release changes over time, it is important to always specify the exact release in the Question, along with details of what you have attempted and any error messages which may have resulted.

Comment: I think the number of tolerance(?)  for snapping (represented by a magnet symbol was 12. This didn't help, i reduced it to zero which also didn't work)